# Subquerying from the same table with aggregates

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I'm learning SQL and I'm trying to answer the following question:

> Which customer spent more money in the 3rd biggest theatre w.r.t. number
> of orders?

This is my **orders** table:

```
+-------------+-------+-----+
| Field       | Type  | Key |
+-------------+-------+-----+
| customer_id | int   | PRI |
+-------------+-------+-----+
| theatre     | text  |     |
+-------------+-------+-----+
| ticket_cost | float |     |
+-------------+-------+-----+
```

This was my first attempt:

```sql
select customer_id, theatre, sum(ticket_cost) as total_paid_eur 
from orders
where theatre= (select theatre
                from orders
                group by theatre
                order by count(*) desc
                limit 1 offset 2) 
group by customer_id, theatre
order by total_paid_eur
limit 1;
```

The problem with this solution is that I'm going through the **orders** table twice and I hope I could do it in a single pass. I already looked into may questions on subquerying and greatest-n-per-group, but as I'm selecting based on aggregates (sum and count) most solutions do not fit.

Is there a way to do it in a single pass or am I bound to it that way?
Many thanks.

UPDATE:
I tried to add an even better description of the problem and simplified it to a "minimum example".

Comment: you can't somehwhere you have to get the third city-

Comment: I added a tag you should investigate.